# Angular 15 matSort doesn't work with progressive rendering in html table

Tags: angular, performance, sorting, angular-material, rendering

I'm using **standart** html table with matSort and it works just fine:

```
<table  id="smart_table" matSort 
            (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortActive="{{sortColumn}}" 
            [matSortDirection]="sortDirIsAsc" >

////

    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of columns" >
            <th mat-sort-header="{{item.field}}"> {{item.name}} </th>
    </ng-container>
```

sortData func:

```
sortData(sort: any) {
        
        function compare(a: any, b:any) {
            a = a[sort.active];
            b = b[sort.active];
            var type = (typeof (a) === 'string' ||
            typeof (b) === 'string') ? 'string' : 'number';
            var result;
            if (type === 'string') result = a.localeCompare(b);
            else result = a - b;
            return result;
        }
        
        return sort.direction == "asc" ? this.data.sort(compare) : this.data.sort(compare).reverse();

    }
```

But as data from server becomes bigger - it takes up to few seconds to render all of the rows. Meanwhile user events in browser are blocked by this rendering process. Not very user-friendly. So i have implemented progressive rendering:

in html(data is not async by itself):

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataItem of data | splitData: useProgressiveRender | async; trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index;">
```

splitData pipe:

```
export class SplitDataPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value: any, useProgressiveRender: boolean = true, takeBy: number = 4, throttleTime: number = 40): Observable<Array<any>> {      
      return useProgressiveRender ? 
          (Array.isArray(value)? this.getSplittedThread(value, takeBy, throttleTime) : of(value)) :
          of(value);
      }
  
    private getSplittedThread(data: Array<any>, takeBy: number, throttleTime: number): Observable<Array<any>> {
      const repeatNumber = Math.ceil(data.length / takeBy);
      return timer(0, throttleTime).pipe(
        map((current) => data.slice(0, takeBy * ++current)),
        take(repeatNumber)
      );
    }
```

And with this pipe sorting just stops applying for some reason. The sortData func still get called and returns correct data, but table data never actually get sorted.

The wierdest part is that **while** its loading progressively - sorting do apply. But not after it's done.

I am using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush (altho removing it did not help) and i'v tried adding this.cdr.detectChanges() or this.cdr.markForCheck() in the sort func - and no effect. I also checked and pipe's transform function get called only on ngOnChanges.

I also tried turning the pipe "off" after 2 second of ngAfterViewChecked() call. But this just made re-render wierd and jumpy.

So i don't know what to do to fix this